# In Python, heapq.heapify doesn't take cmp or key functions as arguments like sorted does

Tags: python

I'm using python2.6. Is it available in higher version of python?
Else is there any other way I can maintain priority queues for list of objects of non-trivial classes?
What I need is something like this

```
>>> l = [ ['a', 3], ['b', 1] ]
>>> def foo(x, y):
...   return x[1]-y[1]
>>> heap = heapify(l, cmp=foo)
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make heapq evaluate the heap off of a specific attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954530/how-to-make-heapq-evaluate-the-heap-off-of-a-specific-attribute)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

## Solution:  Wrap data with the new comparison

Since the builtin functions don't directly support *cmp* functions, we need to build new variants of *heapify* and *heappop*:

```
from heapq import heapify, heappop
from functools import cmp_to_key

def new_heapify(data, cmp):
    s = list(map(cmp_to_key(cmp), data))
    heapify(s)
    return s

def new_heappop(data):
    return heappop(data).obj
```

Those are used just like your example:

```
>>> l = [ ['a', 3], ['b', 1] ]
>>> def foo(x, y):
...    return x[1]-y[1]
...
>>> heap = new_heapify(l, cmp=foo)
>>> new_heappop(heap)
['b', 1]
```

## Solution:  Store Augmented Tuples

A more traditional solution is to store (priority, task) tuples on the heap:

```
pq = [ ]
heappush(pq, (10, task1))
heappush(pq, (5, task2))
heappush(pq, (15, task3))
priority, task = heappop(pq)
```

This works fine as long as no two tasks have the same priority; otherwise, the tasks themselves are compared (which might not work at all in Python 3).

The regular docs give guidance on how to implement priority queues using heapq:

http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes

Comment: I think it's clear that in this case he wants the priorities to be deduced from the objects rather than manually specified.

Comment: This also causes trouble when the tasks are `np.array`s, which don't produce booleans upon comparison

Comment: @Eric Out of curiousity, what would you expect *heapq* to do with an *np.array*?

Comment: My point was more just to provide another example of when the tasks themselves being incomparable is an issue. I wouldn't expect heapq to work on lists of ndarrays.

Comment: So is it always true that the first element of the tuple will be used as the key?

Comment: Using id(task) for the second element of the tuple, using the task as the third should prevent the actual tasks from ever being compared.

Answer (score 41):

Just write an appropriate `__lt__` method for the objects in the list so they sort correctly:

```
class FirstList(list):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self[0] < other[0]

lst = [ ['a', 3], ['b', 1] ]

lst = [FirstList(item) for item in lst]
```

Only `__lt__` is needed by Python for sorting, though it's a good idea to define all of the comparisons or use [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering).

You can see that it is working by using two items with the same first value and different second values. The two objects will swap places when you `heapify` no matter what the second values are because `lst[0] < lst[1]` will always be `False`. If you need the `heapify` to be stable, you need a more complex comparison.

Comment: PEP 8 advises that you define all six comparison and not rely on the implementation details of consumer functions.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger I know that's the general advice, except in this case it's known which is needed -- the use case isn't arbitrary comparison but for a specific purpose. "it is best to implement all six operations so that confusion doesn't arise in other contexts" doesn't apply if you're only operating in one context.

Comment: It is trivial to add ``@functools.total_ordering`` to support all six operations effortlessly.  FWIW, the PEP 8 advice does apply to the content of working with heaps.  The use of \_\_lt\_\_() is an implementation specific detail that is subject to change.  Not long ago, it called \_\_le\_\_() instead.

Comment: I found that when I started using tuples as in @RaymondHettinger's answer, then I got a significant speedup compared to using an ordering defined for the class.

Answer (score 6):

With these `Heap` and `HeapBy` classes I tried to simplify the usage of `heapq`. You can use `HeapBy` to pass a key sorting function.

Note that Raymond said that his [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7810917/1121497) won't work if priorities are repeated and the values are not sortable. That's why I added an example of `HeapBy` with a `NonComparable` class.

I took the `__lt__` idea from [agf's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7803240/1121497).

Usage:

```
# Use HeapBy with a lambda for sorting
max_heap = HeapBy(key=lambda x: -x)
max_heap.push(3)
max_heap.push(1)
max_heap.push(2)
assert max_heap.pop() == 3
assert max_heap.pop() == 2
assert max_heap.pop() == 1

# Use Heap as a convenience facade for heapq
min_heap = Heap()
min_heap.push(3)
min_heap.push(1)
min_heap.push(2)
assert min_heap.pop() == 1
assert min_heap.pop() == 2
assert min_heap.pop() == 3

# HeapBy also works with non-comparable objects.
# Note that I push a duplicated value
# to make sure heapq will not try to call __lt__ on it.

class NonComparable:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

# Using non comparable values
max_heap = HeapBy(key=lambda x: -x.val)
max_heap.push(NonComparable(1))
max_heap.push(NonComparable(1))
max_heap.push(NonComparable(3))
max_heap.push(NonComparable(2))
assert max_heap.pop().val == 3
assert max_heap.pop().val == 2
assert max_heap.pop().val == 1
assert max_heap.pop().val == 1
```

Classes:

```
import heapq

class Heap:
    """
    Convenience class for simplifying heapq usage
    """

    def __init__(self, array=None, heapify=True):
        if array:
            self.heap = array
            if heapify:
                heapq.heapify(self.heap)
        else:
            self.heap = []

    def push(self, x):
        heapq.heappush(self.heap, x)

    def pop(self):
        return heapq.heappop(self.heap)


class HeapBy(Heap):
    """
    Heap where you can specify a key function for sorting
    """

    # Item only uses the key function to sort elements,
    # just in case the values are not comparable
    class Item:
        def __init__(self, value, key):
            self.key = key
            self.value = value
        def __lt__(self, other):
            return self.key(self.value) < other.key(other.value)

    def __init__(self, key, array=None, heapify=True):
        super().__init__(array, heapify)
        self.key = key

    def push(self, x):
        super().push(self.Item(x, self.key))

    def pop(self):
        return super().pop().value
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is terrible and awful and you definitely shouldn't do it… But it looks like the `heapq` module [defines a `cmp_lt` function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/heapq.py#l136), which you could monkey patch if you really wanted a custom compare function.

Comment: Why is it terrible? It works for me! I can even implement max-heap using this approach.

Comment: It's terrible and horrible because, unless you're careful, it will break any other code which uses the `heapq` module, and *horribly* break any other code which tries to monkey patch the `heapq` module.  Better would be to follow the advice of Raymond Hettinger, the author of a number of Python's modules which implement algorithms like this one.

Comment: Ok, it's horrible, but why doesn't `import heapq` and then `heapq.cmp_lt = lambda x, y: x.value < y.value` work? (in my case I'd compare nodes with values).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is better but it is like Raymond Hettinger's solution but the priority is determined from the object.

Let this be your object and you want to sort by the the x attribute.

```
class Item:                                 
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
```

Then have a function which applies the pairing

```
def create_pairs(items):
     return map(lambda item: (item.x, item), items)
```

Then apply the function to the lists as input into heapq.merge

```
list(heapq.merge(create_pairs([Item(1), Item(3)]), 
                 create_pairs([Item(2), Item(5)])))
```

Which gave me the following output

```
[(1, <__main__.Item instance at 0x2660cb0>),
 (2, <__main__.Item instance at 0x26c2830>),
 (3, <__main__.Item instance at 0x26c27e8>),
 (5, <__main__.Item instance at 0x26c2878>)]
```