# python 3 key=lambda heappush

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, lambda, push

This is working well with python2
the 2nd argument type change from str to dict sometimes but that'ok

With pyton3 i have this 
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'str'

I have seen this [TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41913043/typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-tuple-and-str) that understand and [heapq with custom compare predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875706/heapq-with-custom-compare-predicate) with a good answer :

...The functions in the heapq module are a bit cumbersome (***since they are not object-oriented***), and always require our heap object (a heapified list) to be explicitly passed as the first parameter. We can kill two birds with one stone by creating a very simple wrapper class that will allow us to specify a key function, and present the heap as an object....

but a lot complicated to create a new class.

Also https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html in 8.5.2. Priority Queue Implementation Notes section but i want working with tuple(int, str) or tuple(int, dic).

I have seen too [How to use lambdas in python heapq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017037/how-to-use-lambdas-in-python-heapq) seems be good ?

And other interesting ways are [How to make heapq evaluate the heap off of a specific attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954530/how-to-make-heapq-evaluate-the-heap-off-of-a-specific-attribute) and [In Python, heapq.heapify doesn't take cmp or key functions as arguments like sorted does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803121/in-python-heapq-heapify-doesnt-take-cmp-or-key-functions-as-arguments-like-sor)

Is anybody here ? (Jim)

This example programme bug in python3 comes from http://python-prepa.github.io/information_theory.html

```
occurrences={'A': 5, 'R': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 1, 'D': 1}
tas = [(occ, lettre) for (lettre, occ) in occurrences.items()]
heapify(tas)
while len(tas) >= 2:
    print (tas)
    occ1, noeud1 = heappop(tas)
    occ2, noeud2 = heappop(tas)
#    print(type(noeud1))
#    print(type(noeud2))
    t=(occ1 + occ2, {0: noeud1, 1: noeud2})
#    print(occ1,noeud1)
#    print(occ2,noeud2)
#    print(t)
    heappush(tas, t)
#    heappush(tas, (occ1 + occ2, {0: noeud1, 1: noeud2}))
print (tas)
```