# How do I design a set/priority queue in Python 3 paired with a custom comparator for Tuples?

Tags: python, algorithm, set, priority-queue

I'm a Python newbie since I've been coding in C++ and JAVA all along. I was implementing Dijkstra's algorithm which needed me to implement a Priority Queue/Set which stores a Tuple(a,b) where 'a' is a vertex and 'b' is the weight. I the ordering to be according to the 'b' parameter so that when i `a.pop()` where 'a' is my set, the Tuple with the least weight is popped. How do I got about implementing this? All I know is:

```
a=set()
```

I have no idea how to implement the comparator with this. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You can use the [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/heapq.html) module.

Comment: I was looking for a custom comparator with a set. A sample implementation in your answer would help atleast :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954530/how-to-make-heapq-evaluate-the-heap-off-of-a-specific-attribute

Comment: You can just add that as an answer (the 2nd answer on that page). I'll accept it. I don't want to delete the question as it could be useful for someone else